# Has Daredevil every purposely killed someone, knowing what he was doing?

Tags: marvel, daredevil

I know on principle Daredevil doesn't kill, and I know there are just a few cases where he has accidentally killed someone, but I was wondering if there were any times where he, without a doubt, purposely killed someone?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/Category:Killed_by_Daredevil

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In [Daredevil #512](http://marvel.wikia.com/Daredevil_Vol_1_512), a monologue from Daredevil makes it abundantly clear that he intentionally killed Bullseye.

> The decision to take
>   the life of a murderer --
>   **and become one myself...**
>
> That was all me.

[image]

He also killed a pilot in the [Daredevil: Born Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_Again_(comics)) event in 1986

[image]